# R ggplot2 Population Pyramid x and y axis disappear

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to create a population pyramid and the x and y axis are disappear.

My question is that how to let the x and y axis back? For example, the y-axis shows the age group and the x-axis shows the number of genders.

My code is as the following

### 3.4 Data Wangling

```
data <- data %>% mutate(agegroup = case_when(DAYS_BIRTH >= 60   ~ '60-100',
                                             DAYS_BIRTH >= 55  & DAYS_BIRTH <= 59 ~ '55-59',
                                             DAYS_BIRTH >= 50  & DAYS_BIRTH <= 55 ~ '50-55',
                                             DAYS_BIRTH >= 45  & DAYS_BIRTH <= 49 ~ '45-49',
                                             DAYS_BIRTH >= 40  & DAYS_BIRTH <= 45 ~ '40-45',
                                             DAYS_BIRTH >= 35  & DAYS_BIRTH <= 39 ~ '35-39',
                                             DAYS_BIRTH >= 30  & DAYS_BIRTH <= 35 ~ '30-35',
                                             DAYS_BIRTH >= 25  & DAYS_BIRTH <= 29 ~ '25-29',
                                             DAYS_BIRTH >= 20  & DAYS_BIRTH <= 25 ~ '20-25'
                                             ))
```

### 3.5 Population Pyramids

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=agegroup, fill = CODE_GENDER)) + 
  geom_bar(data=subset(data,CODE_GENDER=="F")) + 
  geom_bar(data=subset(data,CODE_GENDER=="M"),aes(y=..count..*(-1)))+ 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-400000,400000,100000),labels=abs(seq(-400000,400000,100000)))+ 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

100 Sample of Data (original has 500k):

```
> dput(out)
structure(list(ID = c(5065438, 5142753, 5111146, 5010310, 5010835, 
5067057, 5095635, 5096402, 5061372, 5026464, 5026032, 5096494, 
5058466, 5088843, 5149050, 5023566, 5095306, 5022248, 5023934, 
5105886, 5022044, 5095735, 5021445, 5095851, 5050878, 5116121, 
5117760, 5135918, 5117163, 5050562, 5061121, 5036943, 5054192, 
5054384, 5148650, 5048416, 5085793, 5054311, 5021709, 5028530, 
5086055, 5117403, 5095009, 5090155, 5117461, 5105584, 5149940, 
5145821, 5086037, 5088919, 5050594, 5023870, 5009603, 5125666, 
5010817, 5069051, 5067456, 5053876, 5115642, 5143360, 5089485, 
5066499, 5028239, 5085896, 5053301, 5021648, 5023339, 5010099, 
5105746, 5143631, 5029097, 5115510, 5091194, 5142806, 5115796, 
5046028, 5042319, 5112626, 5090400, 5022808, 5038881, 5095632, 
5126330, 5025114, 5065348, 5066495, 5021658, 5096210, 5097174, 
5069030, 5022039, 5149635, 5036884, 5089398, 5142761, 5010660, 
5137492, 5125902, 5088914, 5115960), CODE_GENDER = c("F", "F", 
"M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", 
"F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", 
"F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", 
"M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", 
"F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M"), FLAG_OWN_CAR = c("Y", "N", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", 
"Y", "Y", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y"), FLAG_OWN_REALTY = c("N", 
"N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "Y", "Y", 
"N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "N", 
"Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "Y", "N", 
"N", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", 
"Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y"), CNT_CHILDREN = c(2, 
0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2), AMT_INCOME_TOTAL = c(270000, 
81000, 270000, 112500, 139500, 144000, 180000, 405000, 135000, 
270000, 99000, 103500, 225000, 171000, 135000, 270000, 225000, 
202500, 135000, 67500, 225000, 405000, 121500, 225000, 270000, 
560250, 74250, 90000, 135000, 225000, 324000, 391500, 135000, 
292500, 202500, 229500, 157500, 112500, 202500, 171000, 202500, 
94500, 180000, 225000, 148500, 171000, 450000, 202500, 90000, 
157500, 121500, 180000, 112500, 45000, 67500, 225000, 121500, 
157500, 382500, 126000, 315000, 112500, 157500, 112500, 157500, 
292500, 135000, 306000, 112500, 247500, 135000, 81000, 67500, 
180000, 135000, 247500, 202500, 675000, 36000, 180000, 112500, 
180000, 157500, 112500, 202500, 112500, 270000, 81000, 180000, 
157500, 180000, 157500, 180000, 562500, 337500, 270000, 360000, 
103500, 157500, 135000), NAME_EDUCATION_TYPE = c("Secondary / secondary special", 
"Secondary / secondary special", "Higher education", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Secondary / secondary special", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Higher education", "Higher education", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Secondary / secondary special", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Higher education", "Secondary / secondary special", "Higher education", 
"Secondary / secondary special", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Higher education", "Secondary / secondary special", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Higher education", "Secondary / secondary special", "Higher education", 
"Secondary / secondary special", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Secondary / secondary special", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Secondary / secondary special", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Secondary / secondary special", "Higher education", "Higher education", 
"Secondary / secondary special", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Higher education", "Secondary / secondary special", "Higher education", 
"Incomplete higher", "Secondary / secondary special", "Lower secondary", 
"Secondary / secondary special", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Secondary / secondary special", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Higher education", "Secondary / secondary special", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Secondary / secondary special", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Secondary / secondary special", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Secondary / secondary special", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Secondary / secondary special", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Secondary / secondary special", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Secondary / secondary special", "Higher education", "Higher education", 
"Secondary / secondary special", "Higher education", "Higher education", 
"Secondary / secondary special", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Secondary / secondary special", "Higher education", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Higher education", "Higher education", "Higher education", "Higher education", 
"Secondary / secondary special", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Secondary / secondary special", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Secondary / secondary special", "Incomplete higher", "Higher education", 
"Secondary / secondary special", "Higher education", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Higher education", "Higher education", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Higher education", "Higher education", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Secondary / secondary special", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Secondary / secondary special", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Secondary / secondary special", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Higher education", "Higher education", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Higher education", "Secondary / secondary special", "Secondary / secondary special", 
"Secondary / secondary special"), NAME_FAMILY_STATUS = c("Married", 
"Single / not married", "Married", "Married", "Married", "Married", 
"Married", "Married", "Single / not married", "Married", "Married", 
"Married", "Civil marriage", "Single / not married", "Married", 
"Married", "Married", "Married", "Separated", "Married", "Separated", 
"Married", "Married", "Widow", "Married", "Single / not married", 
"Married", "Married", "Separated", "Civil marriage", "Married", 
"Single / not married", "Married", "Single / not married", "Married", 
"Married", "Married", "Married", "Married", "Married", "Married", 
"Married", "Married", "Married", "Married", "Married", "Married", 
"Separated", "Married", "Married", "Married", "Single / not married", 
"Married", "Married", "Married", "Married", "Married", "Married", 
"Separated", "Married", "Married", "Civil marriage", "Married", 
"Married", "Married", "Civil marriage", "Married", "Married", 
"Married", "Civil marriage", "Married", "Married", "Separated", 
"Married", "Single / not married", "Married", "Civil marriage", 
"Married", "Married", "Married", "Civil marriage", "Married", 
"Married", "Widow", "Married", "Civil marriage", "Married", "Civil marriage", 
"Married", "Married", "Married", "Civil marriage", "Married", 
"Married", "Separated", "Married", "Civil marriage", "Married", 
"Married", "Married"), NAME_HOUSING_TYPE = c("With parents", 
"House / apartment", "House / apartment", "House / apartment", 
"House / apartment", "House / apartment", "House / apartment", 
"House / apartment", "House / apartment", "House / apartment", 
"Rented apartment", "House / apartment", "House / apartment", 
"House / apartment", "House / apartment", "House / apartment", 
"House / apartment", "House / apartment", "House / apartment", 
"House / apartment", "House / apartment", "House / apartment", 
"With parents", "House / apartment", "House / apartment", "House / apartment", 
"House / apartment", "House / apartment", "House / apartment", 
"House / apartment", "House / apartment", "House / apartment", 
"House / apartment", "House / apartment", "House / apartment", 
"House / apartment", "House / apartment", "House / apartment", 
"House / apartment", "House / apartment", "House / apartment", 
"House / apartment", "House / apartment", "House / apartment", 
"House / apartment", "House / apartment", "House / apartment", 
"House / apartment", "House / apartment", "House / apartment", 
"House / apartment", "House / apartment", "House / apartment", 
"House / apartment", "House / apartment", "House / apartment", 
"House / apartment", "House / apartment", "House / apartment", 
"House / apartment", "House / apartment", "With parents", "House / apartment", 
"House / apartment", "House / apartment", "House / apartment", 
"House / apartment", "House / apartment", "House / apartment", 
"House / apartment", "House / apartment", "With parents", "House / apartment", 
"House / apartment", "House / apartment", "House / apartment", 
"House / apartment", "House / apartment", "With parents", "House / apartment", 
"House / apartment", "House / apartment", "House / apartment", 
"House / apartment", "House / apartment", "With parents", "House / apartment", 
"House / apartment", "House / apartment", "House / apartment", 
"House / apartment", "House / apartment", "House / apartment", 
"House / apartment", "House / apartment", "House / apartment", 
"House / apartment", "House / apartment", "House / apartment", 
"House / apartment"), DAYS_BIRTH = c(36, 49, 54, 41, 47, 42, 
31, 51, 47, 46, 27, 36, 34, 28, 41, 34, 34, 42, 41, 34, 32, 50, 
36, 57, 36, 36, 55, 44, 44, 46, 37, 38, 31, 38, 42, 46, 39, 56, 
37, 43, 44, 46, 29, 35, 32, 28, 52, 40, 48, 35, 35, 52, 35, 51, 
41, 49, 35, 43, 41, 62, 35, 33, 46, 40, 45, 34, 46, 37, 44, 41, 
32, 35, 30, 50, 40, 33, 24, 54, 40, 33, 51, 31, 46, 62, 42, 33, 
36, 39, 39, 45, 28, 38, 36, 40, 42, 37, 32, 52, 35, 40), DAYS_EMPLOYED = c(6, 
1, 3, 5, 15, 8, 1, 9, 23, 7, 4, 10, 5, 6, 14, 3, 10, 23, 7, 8, 
5, 6, 14, 15, 6, 6, 9, 2, 14, 8, 13, 16, 1, 10, 7, 3, 7, 5, 14, 
1, 8, 4, 4, 6, 10, 3, 2, 13, 3, 16, 4, 5, 10, 10, 9, 7, 4, 2, 
2, 6, 1, 15, 14, 22, 8, 15, 12, 11, 18, 1, 8, 9, 6, 12, 20, 10, 
0, 12, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 39, 11, 15, 4, 0, 2, 4, 4, 7, 3, 8, 1, 
11, 8, 9, 16, 11), JOB = c("Managers", "Private service staff", 
"Laborers", "Core staff", "Drivers", "Core staff", "Drivers", 
"High skill tech staff", "Laborers", "Realty agents", "Managers", 
"High skill tech staff", "Laborers", "Laborers", "Laborers", 
"Laborers", "Core staff", "High skill tech staff", "Core staff", 
"Secretaries", "Core staff", "Managers", "Core staff", "Accountants", 
"Accountants", "Sales staff", "Core staff", "Laborers", "Medicine staff", 
"Laborers", "Managers", "Managers", "Sales staff", "Laborers", 
"Laborers", "Core staff", "Drivers", "High skill tech staff", 
"Laborers", "Sales staff", "Laborers", "Waiters/barmen staff", 
"Laborers", "Core staff", "Sales staff", "Private service staff", 
"Laborers", "High skill tech staff", "Laborers", "Laborers", 
"Medicine staff", "Managers", "Sales staff", "Core staff", "Sales staff", 
"Laborers", "Sales staff", "Managers", "Managers", "High skill tech staff", 
"Managers", "Laborers", "Laborers", "Laborers", "Laborers", "Managers", 
"Sales staff", "Core staff", "High skill tech staff", "Drivers", 
"Managers", "Core staff", "Accountants", "Accountants", "Laborers", 
"Managers", "Core staff", "Managers", "Core staff", "Sales staff", 
"Laborers", "Drivers", "Laborers", "Laborers", "High skill tech staff", 
"Laborers", "Low-skill Laborers", "Low-skill Laborers", "High skill tech staff", 
"Sales staff", "Sales staff", "Sales staff", "High skill tech staff", 
"Managers", "Managers", "Laborers", "Managers", "Cleaning staff", 
"Laborers", "Laborers"), STATUS = c("C", "0", "C", "0", "0", 
"0", "X", "X", "0", "0", "0", "X", "0", "X", "0", "C", "X", "C", 
"0", "C", "C", "C", "C", "X", "C", "0", "0", "0", "C", "0", "X", 
"X", "C", "0", "X", "X", "X", "C", "0", "0", "C", "C", "0", "C", 
"0", "X", "0", "X", "0", "C", "0", "C", "0", "C", "C", "C", "0", 
"0", "0", "C", "X", "C", "C", "C", "X", "X", "C", "C", "0", "0", 
"C", "C", "C", "X", "0", "X", "0", "C", "C", "C", "X", "0", "0", 
"0", "C", "0", "X", "C", "C", "0", "0", "X", "0", "X", "0", "X", 
"0", "C", "0", "C"), TARGET = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), agegroup = c("35-39", "45-49", "50-55", "40-45", 
"45-49", "40-45", "30-35", "50-55", "45-49", "45-49", "25-29", 
"35-39", "30-35", "25-29", "40-45", "30-35", "30-35", "40-45", 
"40-45", "30-35", "30-35", "50-55", "35-39", "55-59", "35-39", 
"35-39", "55-59", "40-45", "40-45", "45-49", "35-39", "35-39", 
"30-35", "35-39", "40-45", "45-49", "35-39", "55-59", "35-39", 
"40-45", "40-45", "45-49", "25-29", "35-39", "30-35", "25-29", 
"50-55", "40-45", "45-49", "35-39", "35-39", "50-55", "35-39", 
"50-55", "40-45", "45-49", "35-39", "40-45", "40-45", "60-100", 
"35-39", "30-35", "45-49", "40-45", "45-49", "30-35", "45-49", 
"35-39", "40-45", "40-45", "30-35", "35-39", "30-35", "50-55", 
"40-45", "30-35", "20-25", "50-55", "40-45", "30-35", "50-55", 
"30-35", "45-49", "60-100", "40-45", "30-35", "35-39", "35-39", 
"35-39", "45-49", "25-29", "35-39", "35-39", "40-45", "40-45", 
"35-39", "30-35", "50-55", "35-39", "40-45")), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: What exactly is your question? Please clarify.

Comment: My question is that how to let the x and y axis back? Thanks @starja

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example?

Comment: ok I try to take only 100 data ( original has more than 500K) @iago Thanks

Comment: @Luke thanks! With your example and exactly the same code I get the y-axis (age group) and the x-axis (title `count` and just a 0, but the same than before applying coord_flip) Have you installed the last version of `ggplot`?

Comment: Thanks @iago My ggplot2 version now is 3.3.2

Comment: Did you get the axis now?

Comment: Still no. dont know the problem

Comment: I have solved the problem by using ggarrange.
so I guess maybe is my original chart over the window limit